# Find $d$ of a plane equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a plane and needed to find some variable

They gave me $2$ planes

$$\pi_1 : 4x-6y-3z-3=0$$
$$\pi_2 : 6x-9y+cz-d=0$$

So the first question was to find the value of $c$ and $d$ for the plane to be Perpendicular so I found $c$ to be equal to $-\frac{9}{2}$, but now I'm really confused on how to find the $d$, could someone give me a clue please.

***Edit 1***
It seem's I was wrong, the answer is 26 and now I'm really confused, since I don't understand why it's not the answer. I did the vectorial product, again could someone point me in the right direction, please

***Edit 2***

In the mean time I did the other question who was : wich value would be the c for them to be parallel confounded, and again I found the c to be $-\frac{9}{2}$, but again I can find the d, I could use some help

Comment: There must be something more given , because there are infinite number of planes perpendicular to given plane , ie there can be many values of $d$ . ( if only this much is given )

Comment: So I guess the answer would be d belong to the real, also I edit the post, if you could check that out, but thank that actually help :P

Answer (score 1):

The value of $d$ doesn't matter because it does not change the angle at which the planes intersect.  It only affects the distance of the plane from the origin.  So, without some other constraint, $d$ can be arbitrary.

To find $c$, the two normal vectors should be perpendicular, so their dot product must be zero.  So,

$$[4,-6,-3]\cdot[6,-9,c]=0$$

Solving this yields $c=26$.

For them to be parallel, you need to set the cross product to zero.

$$[4,-6,-3]\times[6,-9,c]=0$$

Solving yields $c=-\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Yea, I got that with trafalgar law answer, could you check out the edit, please ^^'', I've added something since it gave me the wrong answer...